# razor - check if parameter is null and list has arguments

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of strings and the following code in cshtml

```
@foreach (string tag in Model.TagsList)
{
    <li>@tag</li>
}
```

If I call my page without model I get the following exception 
    Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I check if model is not null and if my list has values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check like this:-

```
@if(Model != null && Model.TagsList != null) //NUll check for Model
    {
       foreach (string tag in Model.TagsList)
       {
          <li>@tag</li>
       }
    }
```

You don't need to check if `TagsList` has values or not (if initialized) if empty `List` it wont throw any error and won't step in to the loop.